# How to resolve NullPointer exception on androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()'

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am getting a null exception pointer in the RecyclerView.java code for my application.  I have attached a screen shot of the debug entries at the point of the exception. As you can see, the holder object is null when executing the holder.shouldIngnore() method.

The application has two fragments (each with different recycler views with LiveData) within another fragment within an activity that is using a tablayout.

I suspect the issue with with identifying the child fragments and need help to resolve.

Have provided as much relevant information as possible to assist. This is my first attempt at two fragments within a fragment.

I only included the first child fragment code in order to fit within the StackOverFlow size limit. The second fragment mirrors the first fragment. 
[image]

[![Debug screenshot][2]][2]

**LogcatEntries**

```
2020-04-02 07:44:27.814 10294-10294/com.grgapps.checkingin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.grgapps.checkingin, PID: 10294
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:4311)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4045)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
```

**The following is the frame layout within the activity tab (fragment_check_in_new_recipients.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CheckInNewRecipients">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_contacts_selection_list_display" />

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_contacts_filter_and_display" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**The following is the first child frame (fragment_contacts_selection_list_display.xml) within the frame from the activity tab.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    tools:context=".ContactsSelectionListDisplay">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/check_in_recipient_selection_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:divider="#467FD7"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_check_in_recipient_selected_list"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

**The following is the second child fragment (fragment_contacts_filter_and_display.xml) within the tabs fragment.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    tools:context=".ContactsFilterAndDisplay">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="108dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_all_contacts"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="328dp"
            android:buttonTint="#2196F3"
            android:drawableTint="#2196F3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/radio_contact_filter_all"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_app_users"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="228dp"
            android:buttonTint="#2196F3"
            android:drawableTint="#2196F3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/radio_contact_filter_app_users"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_by_group"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
            android:buttonTint="#2196F3"
            android:drawableTint="#2196F3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/radio_contact_filter_by_group"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_filter_search"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="304dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:buttonTint="#2196F3"
            android:drawableTint="#2196F3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/radio_contact_filter_search"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/title_contacts_filter"
             />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/check_in_recipient_contacts_list_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:divider="#467FD7"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_check_in_contacts_list" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**The following is the java code for the first fragment (CheckInNewRecipients) within the tablayout.**

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link CheckInNewRecipients.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link CheckInNewRecipients#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class CheckInNewRecipients extends Fragment {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CheckInNewRecipients() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients: ");
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CheckInNewRecipients.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CheckInNewRecipients newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CheckInNewRecipients fragment = new CheckInNewRecipients();
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients newInstance: ");
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients onCreate: ");
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients onCreateView: ");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        ContactsSelectionListDisplay contactsSelectionListDisplay = new
                ContactsSelectionListDisplay(R.layout.activity_check_in_new, getActivity());
        ContactsFilterAndDisplay contactsFilterAndDisplay =
                new ContactsFilterAndDisplay(R.layout.activity_check_in_new, getActivity());

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.check_in_recipient_contacts_list_recycler_view,
                contactsFilterAndDisplay).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.check_in_recipient_selection_list_recycler_view,
                contactsSelectionListDisplay).commit();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_check_in_new_recipients, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients onButtonPressed: ");
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInNewRecipients onAttach: ");
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**The following is the java code for the first child fragment (ContactsSelectionListDisplay.java)**

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ContactsSelectionListDisplay.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ContactsSelectionListDisplay#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ContactsSelectionListDisplay extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter checkInContactSelectionListAdapter;
    //private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private MainViewModel mViewModel;
    private CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter mAdapter;
    private MainViewModelProviderFactory viewModelFactory;
    private TextView checkInContactsPhotoThumbnail;
    private TextView checkInContactsDisplayLastName;
    private TextView checkInContactsDisplayFirstName;
    private TextView checkInContactsListGroups;
    private Context context;
    private ContactsSelectionListDisplay.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ContactsSelectionListDisplay(int layoutID, Context context) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay: ");
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     //* @param param1 Parameter 1.
     //* @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ContactsSelectionLIstDisplay.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ContactsSelectionListDisplay newInstance(int layoutid, Context context) {
        ContactsSelectionListDisplay fragment =
                new ContactsSelectionListDisplay(R.layout.activity_check_in_new, context);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay newInstance: ");
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay onCreate: ");
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        viewModelFactory = new MainViewModelProviderFactory(this.context);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);

        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay onCreateView: ");
        mAdapter = new CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter(R.layout.fragment_contacts_selection_list_display, context);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.check_in_recipient_selection_list_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_selection_list_display, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);

        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay : OnAttach");

        viewModelFactory = new MainViewModelProviderFactory(context.getApplicationContext());
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);


    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay: On Activity Created");

        context = this.getContext();
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);

        mAdapter = new CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter(R.layout.fragment_contacts_selection_list_display, context);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.check_in_recipient_selection_list_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

        observerSetup();
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay onActivityCreated: Observer SetUp");

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback callback = new
                ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {


                    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                        mAdapter.deleteItem(position);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "Item " + (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ? "deleted" : "archived") + ".", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.setDuration(3000);
                        snackbar.setAction(android.R.string.cancel, new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                mAdapter.undoDelete();
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onChildDraw (Canvas c, RecyclerView
                            recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                             int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive){
                        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.recycler_view_item_swipe_left_background))
                                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_archive_white_24dp)
                                .addSwipeRightBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.recycler_view_item_swipe_right_background))
                                .addSwipeRightActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24dp)
                                .addSwipeRightLabel(getString(R.string.action_delete))
                                .setSwipeRightLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
                                .addSwipeLeftLabel(getString(R.string.action_archive))
                                .setSwipeLeftLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
                                .create()
                                .decorate();
                        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                    }
                };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        CustomToast newtoast = new CustomToast(getContext(),"you clicked on this" );
        newtoast.show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
    private void observerSetup() {
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay observerSetup:");
        checkInContactsPhotoThumbnail = getView().findViewById(R.id.checkInRecipientSelectedPhotoThumbnail);
        checkInContactsDisplayLastName = getView().findViewById(R.id.checkInRecipientSelectedLastName);
        checkInContactsDisplayFirstName = getView().findViewById(R.id.checkInRecipientSelectedFirstName);
        checkInContactsListGroups = getView().findViewById(R.id.checkInRecipientSelectedGroups);
        if(mViewModel.getSelectionListContacts() != null)
            Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay getSelectionListContacts != null observerSetup: ");
            Objects.requireNonNull(mViewModel.getSelectionListContacts()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new Observer<List<ContactTable>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<ContactTable> allSelectionListContacts) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplay observer setup onChanged: ");
                    mAdapter.setContactList(allSelectionListContacts);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

**The following is the recycler adapter for the first child fragment (ContactListSelectionAndDisplayAdapter)**

```
public class CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private int contactSelectionListLayout;
    private List<ContactTable> contactSelectionList;
    private List<ContactTable> foundContact;
    private List<ContactTable> foundContactByContract;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ContactTable mRecentlyDeletedItem;
    private ContactTable mContactToDelete;
    private ContactTableDao contactTableDao;
    private ContactTableRepository contactTableRepository;
    private int mContactTablePrimaryKey;
    private int mContactPrimaryKey;
    private int mCheckInRecipientsTablePrimaryKey;
    private String mContactLastName;
    private int mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition;
    private Context context;
    private MainViewModel mViewModel;
    private MainViewModelProviderFactory viewModelFactory;
    //private ArrayList recipientsToDelete = new ArrayList(20);
    private int indexPosition;
    private int index;
    private int numberOfRecipientsToDelete;
    private List<Integer> tableOfContactsToDelete;
    private List<Integer> contactsToDelete;
    private List<ContactTable> contactsToInsert ;
    private ContactTable mContactsTableRecord;
    private MyFirebaseMessagingService myFirebaseMessagingService;

    public CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter(int layoutId, Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter: ");
        contactSelectionListLayout = layoutId;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void setContactList(List<ContactTable> allSelectionListContacts) {
        contactSelectionList = allSelectionListContacts;
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter setContactList: ");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter deleteItem: ");
        indexPosition = 0;
        mRecentlyDeletedItem = contactSelectionList.get(position);
        mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition = position;
        mContactTablePrimaryKey = contactSelectionList.get(position).getContactTablePrimaryKey();
        mContactPrimaryKey = mContactTablePrimaryKey;
        mContactLastName = contactSelectionList.get(position).getContactLastName();

        viewModelFactory = new MainViewModelProviderFactory(context.getApplicationContext());
        mViewModel = new MainViewModel(context.getApplicationContext());
        contactSelectionList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);


    }

    public void undoDelete() {
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter undoDelete: ");
        contactSelectionList.add(mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition,
                mRecentlyDeletedItem);
        notifyItemInserted(mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition);

        //reinsert of record from Contact delete
        mViewModel.insertContact(mRecentlyDeletedItem);

        //reinsert CheckInRecipientsTable records from CheckIn associated delete
        //undoDeleteRecipientsForCheckIn();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter getItemCount: ");
        if (contactSelectionList == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return contactSelectionList.size();
        //return contactSelectionList == null ? 0 : contactSelectionList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder
        onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter onCreateViewHolder: ");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_check_in_contacts_list, parent, false);
        CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder checkInContactListViewHolder = new CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return checkInContactListViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CheckInContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView contactTablePrimaryKey = holder.contactTablePrimaryKey;
        TextView contactLastName = holder.contactLastName;
        TextView contactFirstName = holder.contactFirstName;
        Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter onBindViewHolder: ");

        contactTablePrimaryKey.setText(contactSelectionList.get(listPosition).getContactTablePrimaryKey());
        contactLastName.setText(contactSelectionList.get(listPosition).getContactLastName());
        contactFirstName.setText(contactSelectionList.get(listPosition).getContactFirstName());
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView  contactTablePrimaryKey;
        TextView  contactLastName;
        TextView  contactFirstName;
        TextView  contactThumbnailPhoto;
        TextView  contactGroupsList;
        Button contactSelectedButton;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.i(TAG, "ContactsSelectionListDisplayAdapter ViewHolder: ");
            contactTablePrimaryKey = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInTablePrimaryKey);
            contactLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInContactsDisplayLastName);
            contactFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInContactsDisplayFirstName);
            contactThumbnailPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInContactsListPhotoThumbnail);

            }
         }

    }
```

Comment: I wonder if this might help: https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/issues/585

Comment: I checked the ids and they appear to be OK.   The issue may be with how I am initializing the child fragments (ContactListSelectionDisplay) within the tablayout fragment (CheckInNewRecipients) java code.  Can you look at that and provide observations and/or recommendations.  Thanks

Comment: Note:  There are actually two child fragments within the tablayout fragment, but due to size limitations on stackoverflow questions, I did not include the java code for the second child fragment (ContactFilterAndDisplay).

Comment: I have a question in "fragment_check_in_new_recipients.xml" why are you including two layouts for your fragments in the LinearLayout, i mean if you're gonna use two fragments in a tab navigation why not use ViewPager, backed by FragmentSatePagerAdapter and load your fragments into it, have better control of the flow and animations

Comment: Well this is my first time trying to do the two fragments within another. I am open to a better way to do it. I am using ViewPager for the main tabs and I am not familiar with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.  The two fragments within CheckInNewRecipients are displayed at the same time. When an item in the bottom fragment is selected, it will be added to the top fragment and removed from the bottom fragment.  Does it sound like this will still work?  I will start reading up on the Fragment State Pager Adapter.  If you can respond, I hope I can come back with more questions.  Thanks much!

Comment: Also, I am currently using FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager for the tablayout.

Comment: Ok, let's see if i understand the concept of you implementation, you want to display two fragments both at the same time, you click one item in one of them that item is removed from the recyclerView of this fragment and it gets added to the recycler view of the other fragment, is that correct?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for responding.  I actually simplified the coding and just made it into one fragment with with two recycler views with livedata.  It is working now.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.